# Join Multiple Tables from Single Lookup Table during JOIN

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to output multiple columns and from multiple tables. Normally, I would use an inner join, so I would know what the value of the id is in my lookup table.

```
SELECT  people.*,                    
        category.name AS category_name,
FROM people 
INNER JOIN category ON people.category_id = category.id
```

But I need to do multiple looks to same look up table with the same row data.

I the below case, I would like to know what person has what job, what their category is and also what the "default" job status usually is.

But I can't seem to do two `INNER JOIN`s to the look up table.

I've tried variations on

```
SELECT  people.*,                    
        jobs.* 
        category.name AS category_name,

FROM people p

JOIN jobs AS j ON p.job_id = jobs.id
INNER JOIN category ON people.category_id = category.id
```

But I am afraid I don't know enough about my own question, to figure out what to ask Google.

Any help?

PEOPLE

```
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | name  | job_id | category_id |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
| 1  | Adam  | 1      | 1           |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | Beth  | 2      | 2           |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
| 3  | Clint | 1      | 2           |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+
```

JOBS

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | category  |
+----+-------+-----------+
| 1  | Cook  | 1         |
+----+-------+-----------+
| 2  | Nurse | 2         |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

CATEGORY

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Full-Time |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Part-Time |
+----+-----------+
```

RESULT THAT I WANT

```
+----+-------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | name  | job_id | job_name | job_category | category_id | category_name |
+----+-------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | Adam  | 1      | Cook     | Full-Time    | 1           | Full-Time     |
+----+-------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| 2  | Beth  | 2      | Nurse    | Part-Time    | 2           | Part-Time     |
+----+-------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| 3  | Clint | 1      | Cook     | Full-Time    | 2           | Part-Time     |
+----+-------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join to the `category` table twice, once for the person's category, and once for the job category. This query will do what you want:

```
SELECT p.name, p.job_id, j.name AS job_name, 
       c1.name AS job_category, p.category_id, c2.name AS category_name
FROM people p
JOIN jobs j ON j.id = p.job_id
JOIN category c1 ON c1.id = j.category
JOIN category c2 ON c2.id = p.category_id
```

Output:

```
name    job_id  job_name    job_category    category_id     category_name
Adam    1       Cook        Full-Time       1               Full-Time
Beth    2       Nurse       Part-Time       2               Part-Time
Clint   1       Cook        Full-Time       2               Part-Time
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6287e58/3)

Comment: Is it possible to do a `SELECT *`  for both the people and the job? Or does the second table's columns have to be declared

Comment: You can definitely use `SELECT p.*, j.*, c1.name, c2.name` if that's what you want. I was just going on the columns you gave in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! I very much appreciate it!